# Unkown Disk (disk does not contain a Windows XP-compatible partition) during Windows XP Setup

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, partitioning

I have ATA Toshiba (500 GB) Hard Disk and I am trying to install Windows XP Home Edition. I created several partitions as shown in one of the screenshots. 3 of them are Primary.

[image: Picture from Partition Wizard bootable program]

However, after Many tries, windows setup could not find the disk and showed this message

[image: Windows XP setup error]

What shall I do ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Is it a sata drive?

Comment: Load the necessary drivers for your hardware using F6 during setup.

Comment: It looks like you have an MBR drive with 5 partitions: I understand that this is an extension introduced by MS subsequent to XP. Delete one of the partitions and try again. If the XP installer recognises the drive, then reformat with two of the partitions combined.

Comment: The ability to have more than 4 partitions was introduced by MS in the 80s. XP should support that just fine.

Comment: But seriously … you’re installing XP … in 2017?!

Comment: I used mini tool partition wizard bootable program on a USB to manage the partitions. I do not know if it is allowed to share the source of the Windows, but here we go : http://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/windows-xp-home-edition-sp3-free-download/      and how to load the necessary drivers

Comment: I solved my problem by doing simple thing. Windows XP does not recognize AHCI setting, however, it recognizes ATA. from BIOS I changed the disk to ATA and the setup is about to complete soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From BIOS I changed the settings of the Disk from AHCI to ATA.**

At the end ,setup worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you used a diffrent operating system to partition this disk and it set it up incorrectly. Reset the disk to raw and partition it after windows installed or during installation.

To reset the hdd use an adaptor to plug it into another windows computer (win 7 or 10 is fine) or find another way to get a command prompt while it's plugged in.

Open cmd as administrator.

Enter the following commands...

```
Diskpart

List disk

Select disk # (choose the number that matches your disk from the list disk command)

Clean (this will delete all partitions and any data will be "gone")

Exit

Exit
```

Put it back into the xp computer and it should detect the drive and set it up.

Comment: I used mini tool partition wizard bootable program on a USB to manage the partitions. I will definitely try this solution and get back :)

Comment: I solved my problem by doing simple thing. Windows XP does not recognize AHCI setting, however, it recognizes ATA. from BIOS I changed the disk to ATA and the setup is about to complete soon :)

Comment: In your question you said it was Ata. I assumed since you knew it was ATA you had that part figured out. Glad you got it going. You should put your response in an answer and accept it so this doesn't keep showing up as unanswered.